# Efficient method for tuning threshold in multi-label classification

Tags: classification, multilabel

Given a multi-label classifier, e.g. multi-label image segmentation, what are some typical strategies/libraries to help tune the class label threshold in order to maximize some metric, such as F1-score?

For example, a brute force approach would be to do a grid-search over threshold values over some test data, however this can be inefficient if num labels is large due to the parameter space scaling exponentially with class labels. This process could be slightly optimised by taking a small subsample of test data to speed up the initial threshold search, then subsequently use the full test dataset on a set of best threshold values compute the final F1 score.

Is there a more clever way, outside of a grid search to do this?